# Deploy not working on wildfly on domain mode

Tags: sockets, ssl, deployment, jboss, wildfly

I got a wildfly running on domain mode with two slaves.

Suddenly the deploy stopped working, every time I tried to deploy any simple application it fails.
So I restarted the service on the domain controller and the slave host. I also tried restarting the server groups.
But still the deployment is down for any server group.
The existing deployments work fine but when I try to disable and enable them they failed with the same error.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "address" => [
        ("server-group" => "main-server-group"),
        ("deployment" => "helloWorld.war")
    ],
    "operation" => "deploy"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "result" => undefined,
    "failure-description" => "JBAS010839: Operation failed or was rolled back on all servers.",
    "rolled-back" => true,
    "server-groups" => {"main-server-group" => {"host" => {"machine12" => {
        "server-one" => {"response" => {
            "outcome" => "failed",
            "rolled-back" => true
        }},
        "server-two" => {"response" => {
            "outcome" => "failed",
            "failure-description" => {"JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
                "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"helloWorld.war\".INSTALL"],
                "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"]
            }},
            "rolled-back" => true
        }}
    }}}}
}
```

It seems to be something about the socket binding, but I'm not sure what...

How can I fix this?

Comment: It might be wildfly version difference problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed still:

1. I stopped the all hosts(master and slave) of group
2. I removed the application (war)
3. I deployed the application (war) again
4. I assigned the application to Server Group of my hosts(master and slave)
5. And I started the all host(master and slave) of group